# Calculate the area enclosed by the curve and line

Tags: calculus, area

Calculate the are enclosed by ${y = 2x - 1}$ and ${y=  x^2 + 6x + 2}$

First of all I combine the equations into:

${x^2 + 4x + 3 = 0}$

${(x + 3)(x + 1), x = -3,  x = -1}$

They intersect at ${(-3 -7) (-1, -3)}$

I would say that ${y = 2x  -1}$ is the top equation so to work out the area, I would use:

${\int_{-3}^{-1} (2x -1) - (x^2 + 6x + 2) dx}$

=> ${-{x^3\over 3} - 2x^2 - 3x}$

=> ${(-{1\over 3} - 2 + 3) - ({-27 \over 3} -18 + 9)}$

=> ${{2\over 3} - (-18)}$

=> ${18{2\over 3}}$

This is not the correct answer, can anyone point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You used $y = 2 x - 1$ in your integral instead of $2 x + 1$.

Comment: why would it be ${2x + 1}$?

Answer (score 2):

$(\frac13-2+3)-(9-18+9)=\frac43$ when there are two equation, there are two roots.  You should use
$$\int_{α}^{β}a(x-α)(x-β)dx=-\frac{a}6(β-α)^3$$
for example
$$\frac16(-1-(-3)^2)=\frac43$$

Comment: I think I can work out where you are correcting the OP's work, but your Answer would be improved by explaining a bit more detail of where the mistake is, and why the approach $\frac{1}{6}(\beta - \alpha)^3$ would be preferred.

Comment: @hardmath I am unfamiliar with this technique could you please elablorate

Comment: In my country,this is major formula.

Answer (score 0):

First we calculate the intersection points. We know that as long as the line and the parabola intersect, the line will be on top, because the parabola opens upward.

To solve for the intersection points (which will be our limits), we do the following:
$$2x + 1 = x^{2} + 6x + 2$$
$$x^{2} + 4x + 1 = 0$$
$$x = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{12}}{2} = -2 \pm \sqrt{3}.$$

We need to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-2 - \sqrt{3}}^{-2 + \sqrt{3}} \left(-x^{2} - 4x - 1\right)dx.$$

We do this as follows:
$$\left[-\frac{1}{3}x^{3} - 2x^{2} - x\right]_{-2 - \sqrt{3}}^{-2 + \sqrt{3}}$$
$$= \left(2\sqrt{3} - \frac{10}{3}\right) - \left(-2\sqrt{3} - \frac{10}{3}\right)$$
$$= \boxed{4\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: combining the 2 equations comes out as ${x^2 + 4x + 3}$

Comment: Are you sure? You must subtract $2x + 1$ on both sides @dagda1

Comment: the line equation is ${2x -1}$